# Form Help-Sharepoint

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, infopath

So I am seriously super new to sharepoint, have never worked with it before this. My agency has a client that uses it, and they need to change the e-mail that the form from their website is sent to. I said I could do it because it sounded easy, boy was I wrong!

I have downloaded info path and watched and read all about it. I thought i got it to work by having infopath submit the data to the new email address, but no luck. I then downloaded sharepoint designer to try and change where the email goes through a workflow, but now I can not get the site to open on sharepoint designer. I know this probably comes off as super inexperienced, and thats because it is. I have no idea what I'm doing with sharepoint.

Any help would be super appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Emails from SharePoint always go out as the same account unless you write custom code